# DOM loading computed property before GET request is finished, how to delay?

Tags: vuejs2

I am working on a single page app (Vue-Cli). The DOM Is looking for a value before Vue is done with a GET request. Although the app/data loads fine, the browser gives me an annoying console error: **`Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'branch' of undefined"`**.

> Here's my Template/HTML code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ branch[0].branch }}
  </div>
</template>
```

> Vue instance:

```
  data() {
    return {
      branches: [],
      issue: ''
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getIssue()
    await this.getBranches()
  },
  methods: {
    async getIssue() {
      this.issue = (await axios.getIssue(this.$route.params.id)).data[0]
    },
    async getBranches() {
      this.branches = (await axios.getBranches()).data
    }
  },
  computed: {
    branch() {
      return this.branches.filter(
        branch => this.issue.branch === branch.branch_id
      )
    }
  }
```

How would I correctly "wait" for the BRANCHES to finish loading and THEN filter the branches array and place it in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *conditional rendering* using `v-if`:

```
<div v-if="branch.length">
  {{ branch[0].branch }}
</div>
```

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Alternatively, use a ternary expression:

```
<div>
  {{ branch.length ? branch[0].branch : '' }}
</div>
```

Comment: too much common sense !